# Recording iOS screen with gestures

Tags: iphone, ios, applications

Is there any way (without using accessibility feature) to record mobile screen with gestures like taps?

I need to record how user is using my app and where exactly he taps.

I found solution with **Assistive Touch** and new adding new gesture.
But while recording we have additional annoying home button on the screen and also tap circle. This can distract person while using my app.

I am afraid that this is a technical limitation of the apple system.
But I hope I’m wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Try this
http://www.uxrecorder.com/

I can‘t use it - not available in german store